# Reading and printing data by Python Tkinter parts

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I need to make a simple hex-viewer on Tkinter. I found the source on the Internet, but it is without Scrollbar. The problem is that I can not set the required interval for the scroll widget. Large files need to be read and output in parts, while the entire file must scroll.
How can this be realized? And is it possible on Tkinter?

Comment: it is possible, but you would have to implement the partial loading functionality yourself. the scrollbar linking would normally be done so that the container widget (text?) would control the scrollbar directly to set the size and position of the thumb, however you could write your own functions  to go in the middle to interpret any movements, clear the text widget and load new content etc. but there isn't any built in capability.

Answer (score 0):

I found two solutions to this problem:

1. Draw a scroll in the tkinter.Canvas
2. Use the widget
   tkinter.Scale as the scroll

[Screenshot Hex-Viewer (tkinter.Scale)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oslo.png)